# Compiling Fortran using Ifort for Linux under Windows

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio-2010, fortran, intel-fortran

I develop and run some Fortran Code under Windows (7, 64 bit) using Visual Studio 2010 and ifort.

The code, mostly compiled to a DLL file, is tested on Windows and is deployed approx. 25% of the time to Windows ([Windows 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_2000) up to [Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7)) and 75% to [SUSE Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux). While the Windows solution is completely handled by me, the Linux "branch" is compiled by someone other (it is 100% the same code). The Linux branch is compiled with the g95/NAG compiler.

Due to some decisions out of our control, we will change from NAG to gfortran. After some tests, we found the code compiled with gfortran (and some optimisation like `-o2`) to take about double the time to finish compared to Windows and ifort (no optimisation, full debug). We had a chance to compile the code under Linux and ifort and got about the speed of Windows + ifort. (NAG compiled code is somewhere in between.)

For obvious reasons, we would like to compile the code with ifort for Windows and Linux, so:

Is it possible to compile for SUSE Linux under Windows with ifort (using cmd or Visual Studio 2010)?

Comment: Much better to ask Intel directly, when you pay for your support. AFAIK it is not possible. You can just install Linux in a virtual machine.

Comment: AFAIK installing Linux in a VM won't make me able to compile with ifort on that machine. Best solution would be to hit "compile" an get a .dll and a Linux shared object.

Comment: Why do you think so? A virtual machine with Linux is a full festured system. You can do anything there. Your "best solution" would have to be supported by the vendor. Ask them, but  don't believe the do it.

Comment: I see your point, but this way i'll have to install ifort on the VM, and this wouldn't change much on our current solution. So i take it there is no way to compile from windows+ifort for linux and the answere to my question is simply `no`.

Comment: Ask your vendor. You pay for the support!

Comment: Although i'm not arroused by the answere, the support at intel is realy fast. Got an reply from them stating that they don't and won't support cross compilation between different os.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer for Intel - no, you can't compile for Linux in Windows (except using a VM in which case you are really running Linux, as stated above). A VM is a reasonable approach, but you'll have to buy a separate license for ifort on Linux.

Or, as I assume you have a Linux box you will test on, build there (you can SSH to it from your Windows box.) True, you won't have the Visual Studio IDE, but some of our customers use [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) (with the Photran plugin) or [Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks) with Intel Fortran.